# Excel - How to lock whole row if cell in Column G contains *

Tags: excel

I have a rather large excel sheet (4500+ rows) which is an output from a powershell script. when the script couldn't find the answer and we have manually found information have column N (lock Cell) show TRUE .

[image: Excell]

What I would like to do is lock the entire row if the cell in column N contains text TRUE.

I would assume this is done via VBA but I not versed in VBA so really don't have a clue on it. I am good at following instructions if someone can write some steps.

The end goal is that we would like to be able to run our powershell script in the future and not overwrite manually found information hence the need to lock rows containing a *

Is this possible?

As always thank you for your help

_____________UPDATE _____________

I have adjusted my sheet to have a new column and then created the following VBA script

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("N:N") = "TRUE" Then
        Range("2:10000").Locked = True
    ElseIf Range("N:N") = "FALSE" Then
        Range("2:10000").Locked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible with vba.  As to the steps, you just loop the range and check if it has `*` using instr().  Then lock the cells and at the end protect the sheet.  Try writing your own and come back when you hit a specific snag.  Asking for steps or help to do the full work is too broad here.

Comment: Thanks @Scott. I will dig in further.

Comment: Well my idea didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the tab you wish to protect>>>> View code.

Then I inserted this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Me.Unprotect
For i = 1 To LR
    With Range("N" & i)
        If .Value = "TRUE" Then .EntireRow.Locked = True
    End With
Next i
Me.Protect
End Sub
```

It appears to be working, now to figure out the next part.